# Can't access home folder

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

While installing Matlab, I mistakenly typed `sudo chmod +x ./java` in the home folder.

And I got i/o error that you are not allowed to access the home folder. Suddenly everything in my home folder disappeared.

Although the disk shows filled up data. I guess the folder permission need to be changed.

Comment: first see your home folder permission ls -l.if there have't any execute permission then give permission with 744 or u+x;

Comment: ls -l does not show anything......should I just type chmod u+x?

Comment: I question your diagnosis. Simply running `chmod +x ./java` as `root` will not break access to `$HOME`. Do `ls -ld $HOME;echo $HOME` to show `$HOME` permissions, and to verify `$HOME` makes sense. My `$HOME` is mode `0700 (rwx------)`. `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=,o= $HOME` is my suggestion. `sudo chmod u=rwx,g=rx,o= $HOME` to allow group read and search. `man chmod`

Comment: ls -ld shows:dr-xr-xr-x 10 root root 2048 2011-09-23 21:47

Comment: I agree with waltinator. It doesn't make sense for that command to change ownership and remove write permissions. Do you maybe have a wrapper on `sudo` or `chmod`? Also you didn't even need to run `chmod` as root, since I assume you're the file owner. (BTW I realize this is an old post -- just commenting for future readers.)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to chown the directory back to yourself.

```
sudo chown -R user /home/user
```

Comment: According to the comments, the owner doesn't have write permissions, so OP will also need to run `chmod u+w /home/user`.

Comment: And the group ownership was changed to, so instead of just `user`, use `user:` in the `chown` command.

Comment: Also do you need to make it recursive? Aren't there files in the home folder that are supposed to be owned by root, or am I thinking of something else?